# Unable to run bootable USB of ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: system-installation

My laptop having ubuntu 16.04 isn't working. So, I created a bootable USB of ubuntu 16.04.1 from my friend's laptop having Windows 7 using Rufus. I  tested the USB in his laptop. I rebooted his laptop and successfully entered in the live ubuntu via the created bootable USB. I came home and it was too disgusting to find that the USB failed to load the live ubuntu. When my laptop booted with USB drive plugged in, I got the below message and got stuck there.[image]
What may be the issue please?

Comment: It may have to do with legacy vs UEFI booting. I've found Ubuntu Live USB flash drives unreliable. If you can burn the .iso to a DVD, and boot to the DVD, you have much better luck. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema Can I try one more time creating a bootable USB of Ubuntu, but this time I will use a different application other than Rufus which I used last time? Last time, I created 2 different bootable USB drives in my friend's laptop. Both drives worked on his laptop but failed in mine. So, does it make any sense in trying a different application than Rufus to create a bootable USB drives? Can it work on my laptop?

Comment: It may still not work, for the reasons I mention earlier. Use the DVD approach if you can. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema just now I tested DVD approach. After trying to burn many DVDs, 1 finally got burnt successfully as displayed in the friend's windows laptop. But that didn't work on either his laptop nor mine while booting the laptops. Can you please suggest any other way?

Comment: What happens when you try and boot the DVD? Error messages? Anything at all? Why did you have to burn so many DVD's? Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema the laptop sounds in DVD drive suggesting that it is trying to read from it but then after making sound for a while, it boots the laptop internal hard disk drive. So there is no point that any error message will appear, it just means that it fails to boot the DVD. The reason to try burning many DVDs is that all other DVDs after trying to burn for a while in the burner in Windows 7, were throwing error messages. I didn't note the exact error but it was something like "an error has occurred while burning ..... blah blah", error code might be mentioned there.

Comment: Now I'm not trusting the DVD you finally burned. **Download the .iso again**, and trying burning the .iso on another computer. If you can get a working DVD, you won't have any more problem. Keep me posted. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema O.K. I need some time. I will update you as soon as I am through. But rather than downloading the iso again, I would check what I missed earlier and that is the SHA256SUMS and MD5SUM of the previous download. I hope you would be fine with that?

Comment: Yes, the checksum of the original .iso download would be fine. Cheers, Al